# accelerate sparse point deformation in Metal

Tags: ios, gpgpu, metal

I have a Metal kernel function wich only modifies vertices within some distance to a point.

Currently I'm running this kernel on all vertices in my data, which is expensive when only a few of the vertices fall within the distance.

**How can I accelerate this for repeated applications of the deformation?**

If I were implementing this on the CPU, I would bin the points into a regular grid, so grid cells outside the radius can be rejected. On the CPU side, it would be easy to move points between bins. **Can this approach be achieved using metal?**